# Display image in jquery ui dialog onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display an image in a jquery dialog after it is clicked. I know there are already questions out there about expanding pictures, but I can't understand why something like this doesn't work:

```
    $('img').click(function () {
        $('body').append('<div id="dialog" title="image"><img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" width="300" /></div>');
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    });
```

Comment: Your code is just fine,only if there is multi nodes with id=dialog,the return of $('#dialog') is not the node u just added.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the html to the body not to the dialog. this will work:

```
 $('img').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').append('<div id="dialog" title="image"><img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" width="300" /></div>');
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    });
```

However I guess in most cases the  `$("#dialog").html()` would be better than `$("#dialog").append()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess make sure you have UI library loaded.

Works here if that's what you'r after:

[]: jsfiddle.net/fhb1ytdb/